# "Послужной список" в отношении к шоу-звезде, фрилансеру

Tags: семантика

Можно ли сказать, что какая нибудь шоу-звезда проходит службу, занимается служебной деятельностью? Применимо ли понятие "послужной список" к звезде шоу-бизнеса или, например, к фрилансеру? Ведь это понятие также может употребляться в переносном смысле.

Answer (score 1):

В XIX-м веке можно было сказать об актрисе, что она служит в Императорском театре. Сегодня этот оборот представляется устаревшим.

В отношении фрилансеров слово "служит" не было пригодно раньше и непригодно сейчас, ибо они не состоят ни на чьей службе.

Можно, разумеется, сказать, что актриса или актёр служат музам, но по отношению к представителям шоу-бизнеса это почти всегда будет звучать насмешливо.

Словосочетание "послужной список" может использоваться, но его употребление применительно к звёздам шоу-бизнеса и вообще к представителям богемной среды требует осторожности. В зависимости от контекста, это словосочетание может иметь пикантную коннотацию.

Answer (score 0):

Если звезда проходит службу, то она служит. Захотите ли вы сказать, что звезда служит на съёмках? Кому она там служит?

А вот "послужной список" применим в обоих случаях (звезда, фрилансер). Он не связан со службой, это значение устарело:
Послужной список (**устар.**) — документ, содержащий сведения о прохождении службы.
[https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/послужной+список](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Словарь:
[image]

Comment: Вы говорите "Кому служит" — она обслуживает культурные потребности народа.

Comment: "Обслуживает" — это другое, но обслуживают кого-то или какое-то устройство, а не потребности. Так кому служит? Чьи приказы выполняет?

Comment: В ответ добавлена словарная статья. Какое значение вам нужно? Там только подходит пункт 5, но это не официальная служба.